# Why does this happen in the linear program?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, binary-programming

Use the BIP brach and cut algorithm to solve the following problem interactively.

$$\max \ z=2x_1-x_2+5x_3-3x_4+4x_5\\ s.t. 3x_1-2x_2+7x_3-5x_4+4x_5\le6\\ x_1-x_2+2x_3-4x_4+2x_5\le0 \\ x_j \\ binary$$

Attempt

First consider $x_1=0$, thus the new LP is $$\max \ z=-x_2+5x_3-3x_4+4x_5\\ s.t. -2x_2+7x_3-5x_4+4x_5\le6\\ -x_2+2x_3-4x_4+2x_5\le0 \\ x_j \\ binary$$

When solving this new LP using software yields *no optimal solution* which can be taken as a correct answer.

Then when I consider $x_1=1$ and after the substitution on the original LP, the software gives again the same answer *no optimal solution*.

From here I cannot construct the next brach, so the LP has no solution?

However I checked the solution given at the end of the book and it is $(0,0,1,1,1)$ with $z=6$.

Why is that?

I don't think the software it's wrong because I've tested with other LP's and returns the correct answer.

Could someone please help?

Comment: The software I am using is online, http://simplex.tode.cz/en/#steps

Comment: so what you solved with that tool was the LP relaxation?

Comment: Hi @LinAlg :) .yes. I really don't understand where is the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably made a mistake as you entered the problem. I tried the problem with $x_1=0$ (since that eventually leads to a solution) and got x* = (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0). I have added my input of the LP relaxation below:

[image]

Comment: ops yes indeed I was typing it wrong. Now this gives actually the $z^*=6$, thank you!

Comment: With $x_1=1,$ returns $z=4$, then no more branch will be from there because it is smaller than $z=6$ right?

Comment: @Alt. If indeed it returns 4, then yes, no need to branch further.

Comment: Well not exactly, it was $\frac{30}{7}$ which is aprox. $4.3$, so $4.$ Thus the final answer would be $x_1=0=x_2,x_3=1=x_4=x_5$ with $z=6$ right?

Comment: @Alt. right. Typically you write it as $x_1=x_2=0$, $x_3=x_4=x_5=1$.

Comment: Alright. thank you again.

Comment: Hi LinAlg, could you help me here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173601/game-theory-two-person-zero-sum-game-problem please?